# If a 2*2 matrix has only one independent vector then which of the following is necessarily true?

Tags: matrices

If a 2*2 matrix has only one independent eigen vector then which of the following is necessarily true?

1. Inverse does not exist
2. There must be a repeated eigen value
3. The matrix is non diagonalizable

I am sure about 2 and 3. I believe the 1 is not right. Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Proof that (1) is false:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about 2 and 3.

To 1:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$